# Why servlet don't send json custom string or Ajax don't receive it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I made this servlet that response with a simple json list:

```
public void aggiungiCategoria(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     logger.log(Level.INFO, "Aggiungo la categoria");
     ObjectifyService.register(Studente.class);
     ObjectifyService.register(Categoria.class);
     String idS=req.getParameter("ids");
     String idC= req.getParameter("idc");
     Studente s=ofy().load().type(Studente.class).id(Long.parseLong(idS)).now();
     System.out.println(s.getNome());
     if(s!=null){
         Categoria c=ofy().load().type(Categoria.class).id(Long.parseLong(idC)).now();
         System.out.println(Key.create(Categoria.class, c.id));
         s.addCategoria(Key.create(Categoria.class, c.id));
         ofy().save().entity(s).now();
         StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        // sb.append("[");
         for(Key k : s.getCategorie()){
             Categoria c1=ofy().load().type(Categoria.class).filterKey(k).first().now();
             System.out.println(c1.getNome());
             sb.append("{");
             sb.append("id: ");
             sb.append("'"+c1.getId()+"', ");
             sb.append("nome: ");
             sb.append("'"+c1.getNome()+"'},");
         }
         sb.append("{}");
         System.out.println("Aggiunto: "+sb.toString());
         resp.setContentType("application/json");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
         resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         resp.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
     }
}
```

the example output for only one item in the DB is:

{id: '4749890231992320', nome: 'c2'},{}

In my javascript code there is a right menu click on a table. When a user add an item of the table, start the ajax request who if success update another table with the data of the servlet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}   
console.log(); 

$('#contacts tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu1', {
bindings: {
    'open': function(t) { AddAction(t, "Open"); },
    'email': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Email"); },
    'save': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Save"); },
    'delete': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Delete"); }
}
});

function AddAction(t, a) {
$.ajax({
    url : 'studenteServlet?   action=aggiungiC&ids='+$.urlParam('id')+'&idc='+t.id,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#catAssociate tbody > tr').remove();
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    html += '<tr><td id='+data[i].id +'>' + data[i].nome + '</td></tr>';
        $('#catAssociate').append(html);
    }
   });
}

 function ShowAction(t, a) {
alert('Trigger was ' + t.id + '\nAction was ' + a + "\nHtml is " + $(t).html());
```

}
          });

If i change the content type with "text/html" the data is sent. I made this example using this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/FXJrG/) Thanks!

**EDIT** - I resolved with:

```
sb.append("[");
         for(Key k : s.getCategorie()){                         
                 Categoria c1=ofy().load().type(Categoria.class).filterKey(k).first().now();
                 sb.append("{");
                 sb.append("\"" +"id"  + "\" : \"" + c1.getId() + "\",");
                 sb.append("\"" +"nome"  + "\" : \"" + c1.getNome() + "\",");
                 sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
                 sb.append("},");

         }

         sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));   
         sb.append("]");
```

But now i have problem with draw the table. It stamp nothing on the web page.

Comment: your json isn't valid. I suggest stop writing json yourself and use one of the existing libraries that will do it for you (if your server-language doesn't already have it built-in)

Comment: Thanks! so I tryed this
 JSONObject js= new JSONObject();
 for(Key k : s.getCategorie()){
 Categoria c1=ofy().load().type(Categoria.class).filterKey(k).first().now();         js.put("id", c1.getId());
 js.put("nome", c1.getNome());
    }
But it stamp only one item.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you are using, but it looks like your for loop would just replace the previous entry on each iteration. you need the equivalent of an array containing objects.

Comment: I resolved the problem with the json. The problem now is to draw the table in jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my answer. The example works fine now!